# form input nao digita

Tags: php

porém onde digita o cep , não está digitando nada,como faço para resgatar o cep digitado numa variavel com $post ? e no botao calcular eu queria redirecionar para calculo.php,algo semelhante a isto:

```
<input name="postok" type="button" id="postok" value="Calcular" onClick="calculoFrete();">
```

alguem pode ajudar?

eis o código:

```
echo'<form action="" method="post">';
echo'<tr><td colspan = "4" bgcolor = "ffffff"></td align = "center"><h4>Tipo de Entrega&nbsp;<select id = "tipo" name = "tipo" title = "Servicos dos Correios" class = "select" tabindex = "1"></h4><option value = "PAC" style = "font-size: 25px;">PAC</option><option value = "SEDEX" style = "font-size: 25px;">SEDEX</option>
</select><br />Informe aqui o Cep para calcular o frete:<input name="cepDestino"  style = "font-size: 18px;" autocomplete = "off" type="text" id="cepDestino"><br /><td>';
echo'</td><input type = "submit" id = "pesquisar" name ="pesquisar"  style = "font-size: 18px;" autocomplete = "off" tabindex = "2" class="button" value = "calcular"/></form></td';
echo '<tr>';
```

Comment: sempre inclua o código fonte em suas perguntas

Comment: Se não está usando ajax, tem que por o destino do form no action: `<form action="calculo.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

Para resgatar o cep digitado em um formulário com a tag input do html você precisa utilizar o recurso da linguagem PHP que é chamado de variáveis superglobais. As superglobais estão disponíveis em todos os escopos, sendo assim você pode definir uma variável normal, de modo que ela receba uma superglobal.

Por exemplo:

$cep = $_POST['input_cep'];

Há um montão de variáveis superglobais, fica a seu critério qual utilizar. Por exemplo, você poderia utilizar $_GET se fosse uma requisição do tipo GET; ou até $_REQUEST, esta funciona com todos os tipos de requisição.

Lembrando que essas que eu citei são arrays associativos, pois podem ser acessados por índices numéricos ou textuais. Nesse caso o índice será o atributo name do seu input txt.

Se você quer redirecionar para outra página PHP através de um botão, você precisa especificar isso na abertura da tag form.

Por exemplo:

...

Depois você pode dar um echo para exibir a variável $cep.